# MacBook Pro mirror-like screen

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I have MacBook Pro at work. It has the glossy glass screen and I'm able to see everybody behind me by just changing the focus of my sight. It's a bit weird.

How do you get used to this mirror/screen?

Comment: Non-glossy screens are available when ordering, at a premium.

Comment: Some newer laptops (like [MacBook Airs since late 2010](http://www.marco.org/2010/10/20/the-new-macbook-air) and retina MacBook Pros) no longer have glass screens, but less reflective plastic glossy surfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a matter of time. You do eventually get used to it (I had to). However, the glare will almost always be noticeable. Unfor tunately, this is because of the glass used on the screen. If this is really bothersome, make sure you order the non-glossy screen (another $150). The new retina display MacBook Pro and the newer MacBook Airs have a less glossy screen that the current MacBook Pros.

If it really bothers you now, you may want to look into getting a screen protector. [Here](http://www.macworld.com/article/1138610/mbpantiglare.html) is a MacWorld article comparing a couple protectors. I also found [one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001N4BHJA) on Amazon. I will note that I have never used on of these.

Comment: yeah at least there is a choice to buy non-glossy one. then it is not so bad (for me to realize).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use something like a 3M privacy filter to give it a bit more of a matte appearance and reduce the glare.

Comment: it see. it sounds strange/weird as well. I mean when I buy such thing like MacBook I assume that it is smart thing and confortable to work with (especially if compare with 'general'/cheaper laptops). Maybe new screen will be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to either invest in a matte-style screen protector as others have suggested or to adjust the screen in ways that reduce the glare problem.  I usually combat glare problems by increasing brightness or just moving the laptop around until I find a good spot with minimal glare.  That said, you do get used to the reflections over time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is something you can get used to if it really irritates you.

The obvious solutions or countermeasures to control reflected light from the glass screen are available:

- Apply a surface film or treatment to diffuse the reflections.
- Apply a polarization filter. (Polarized glasses could potentially help, but I've never been happy with polarized glasses indoors looking at an LCD for more than a moment to entertain myself. The 3M privacy filters however are incredibly good if that's your thing.)
- Investigate computer distance specific glasses to reduce eye strain so your eyes can focus for longer times on the screen than the reflections. (I have seen incredible increases in comfort from having your optometrist check your eyes for close focus and any need for correction there.)
- Control the lighting ratio between the items behind you and your immediate workspace. A bright tasklight on the keyboard and above the display will not reflect from your display and will reduce your eye's sensitivity to reflected light from the screen.
- Control the angle of the screen (send the offensive reflections above your eye level if possible).
- Screen your work area from behind (above or below depending on the angle you can accept for the main screen. I have seen a matte partition hanging above standing eye level work wonders for people that work with the glassy cinema displays and other countermeasures have failed).

You could try the easiest of these and hope that in time your eyes learn to focus near so the reflections are out of focus, but unless this irritation is quite new, your eyes may have adapted as much as they can and you will need to look into a different location or exchange the machine for a different display. The Air and Retina MacBook pro are not as reflective as the glassed over displays but also not nearly as anti-reflective as the optional wide-screen anti-glare display that you can configure on some of the 15 inch MacBook Pro models.